# Why do we need a constructor in OOP?

Tags: oop, methods, constructor

I am new to OOP. I am still in a learning phase.

Why do we need constructors, When we can initialize the values of the properties (variables) by writing a "Initialize function"?

Basically why do we write a constructor when we can achieve the same results even by writing a function for initializing the variables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The constructor IS the "Initialize function"

Rather than calling two functions

```
object = new Class;
object.initialize();
```

You just call

```
object = new Class();
```

The logic inside the constructor can be identical to the logic inside the initialize function, but it's much tidier and avoids you naming your function initialize(), me naming mine initialize_variables(), and someone else naming theirs init_vars()... consistency is useful.

If your constructor is very large, you may still wish to split variable initialisation into a separate function and calling that function from your constructor, but that's a specific exception to the scenario.

Comment: This is not really true. In many languages, constructors cannot call other constructors and thus there is a requirement for a separate initialise function that is either called externally or by each overload of the constructor. There are also patterns where objects are constructed up front and initialised on first use. There are also very useful patterns that demand named, static factory methods that call a private or protected constructor.

Comment: Again, that's an exception to the "standard" where you may wish to use a separate function to initialize variables (or perform other processing "shared" by each instantiation of the object). It does not remove the usefulness of a constructor, nor imply that a constructor should be replaced by a variable initialization function. In specific circumstances, there is nothing to stop you leaving the constructor blank and calling other functions, but that does not change the concept of a constructor in the OOP paradigm.

Comment: I am not arguing that constructors are useless, only that constructors != initialise methods. They both have their reasons for existence. This answer suggests that initialise methods are never more than refactoring tools so that all the code isn't bundled into one constructor method. That, frankly, is not true.

Comment: Yes you are :) to quote your question: "Why do we need constructors". One use of an initialize method is to refactor code from a constructor, I only gave that as an example of why you may wish to still use one.. it wasn't an exhaustive list. Either way, I've explained my reason I believe we need constructors.

Comment: It isn't my question. I posted an answer below, before my comments. Read it. If you still think I am arguing that constructors are useless, I give up. You're free to think what you like.

Comment: My apologies, I confused the usernames :) while I don't disagree with the usage you show in your answer (it being another time when an initialize function is useful) I don't think that detracts in any way from my answer to the question originally asked.

Comment: thank you JonStory and @Xharlie both of your answers helped me! :)

Answer (score 5):

So answer is simple
Why do we write Constructor?
Because in C you can write,
 `int i;`

if write like this In above case data type and variable defines if you define like this memory allocated for `i` variable.So simple here we define class name and variable name(object name) we can create memory allocated for class name.

Example
**myClass objectName;**

But in C++ new keyword is used for dynamic memory allocation, so this dynamic memory which we can allocate to our class but here my example `myClass` is our class and we want to allocate to dynamic memory allocated.

So

`myClass objectName = new myClass();`

and simply constructor is memory allocation for class variable is called the constructor.`

Answer (score 3):

the role of the constructor is to initialize the variables/values.it is the "initialization function".The only reason i find on why we use a constructor instead of a normal function to initialize the variables is to stop different people from using different function names and avoid ambiguity and it is much more easier to use a constructor which is instantiated automatically as soon as the class is run,instead of having to write a separate code for instantiation.this may seem small and like something that doesn't require much work,but only for a very small program,for larger ones the struggle is real.

Answer (score 2):

It is usual to put mandatory things into the constructor and optional ones into the `Initialise` function.

For example, consider an amplifier that *requires* a power source so that would be supplied to its constructor. Logically, you may want to turn it on and set its power level but one could argue that you might not want to do that until later. In pseudo-code:

```
class Amplifier
{
    public Amplifier(PowerSource powerSource)
    {
        // create amplifier...
    }

    public int PowerLevel;

    public void Initialise()
    {
        // turn on...
    }
}
```

The example, above, is rather puerile but it illustrates the concepts at play. It is always an issue of design, however, and opinions do vary.

Some classes of object, however, will have to perform obvious set-up operations during their construction phase. In these cases, the requirement to have a constructor is very easy to understand. For example, if your object might require a variable amount of memory, the constructor would be a logical place to allocate it and the destructor or finaliser would be a logical place to free it up again.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't use constructor it will call implicitly by your language translator whenever you create object.Why?

The reason is that it is used for **object initialization** means the variable(instance) which we declare inside our class get initialized to their default value.

```
class Person {
    //Class have two parts
    //1.Data(instance variable)
    //2.Methods(Sub-routine)
    String name;
    int age;
  }
  public class Stack{
      public static void main(String[] args){
         Person person1 = new Person();
         System.out.println("Name: "+person1.name);
         System.out.println("Age: " + person1.age);
      }
  }
```

Output- Name: null
        Age: 0

"null" and "0" are default values which are impicitly set by default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

When we initialize a class by creating an instance or object the constructor is called automatically. This is very helpful when we need a huge amount of code to be executed every time we create an object.

**The best use of constructor can be seen when we create a " graphical user interface". While building a GUI for an application we need to separate the code for designing the GUI and the business logic of the application. In such a case we can write the code for designing GUI, in a constructor and business logic in respective methods. This make the code tidy and neat too.**

Also when an object is created the global variables can be initialized to their default values using constructor. If we don't initialize the global variables, then the compiler will do it implicitly by using the default constructor.

So constructor is a very wise concept which appears to be an idiosyncrasy at first but as you code further and more and more you will realize it's importance.

Answer (score 0):

Because constructors are exactly for that: to avoid using an "initialize function"

Plus you can have have as many constructors as you want: you juste feed them some parameters, depending how you want to inialize your object.

Comment: re "All the constructors call the constructor of the Object class" that is not true in all languages several do not have a root Object class - others have a choice of Object classes

Comment: you are right, I have taken your remark into account

Comment: and object construction is not polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is a special member function which has same name as class name and called whenever object of that class is created. They are used to initialize data field in object.

Constructor has following properties:

1. It has same name as class name.
2. It is called whenever object of a class is created.
3. It does not have return type not even void.
4. It can have parameters.
5. Constructor can be overloaded.
6. Default constructor is automatically created when compiler does not find any constructor in a class.
7. Parameterized constructor can call default constructor using this() method.
8. A constructor can be static for static data field initialization.
9. It is not implicitly inherited.

For More Info
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)