# Constructor() in class{}: why is it needed?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

basic question: why is the constructor needed in class?

Below is a simple test:

- Circle class with a constructor function
- Circle2 class without a constructor function.
- ... However, both classes work and an instance can be created.

Going back to the topic, why is the constructor needed in class?

```js
class Circle {
  draw() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

c = new Circle(1);

class Circle2 {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  
  draw() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

c2 = new Circle2(1);
```

Comment: Your first `Circle` has no radius. That seems like pretty good reason to add a constructor.

Comment: Technically your example there works, but now try adding a "calcArea()" function to both of those classes. You will only be able to do so with Circle2, because you never store the radius in Circle1.

Comment: [Why do we need a constructor in OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424511/why-do-we-need-a-constructor-in-oop)

Comment: There’s always a default constructor which is essentially equivalent to `constructor(){}` in base classes and to `constructor(){ super(); }` in derived classes. You don’t _need_ the constructor, but if you’re going to supply arguments to your class, how are you going to accept them without a constructor?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the perspective. 

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424511/why-do-we-need-a-constructor-in-oop) was illuminating

Answer (score 1):

if you do `c.radius`, it has not been defined, but `c2.radius` will be

When you dont have the constructor, your class will take in arguments but wont do anything with them

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. its sinking in and your answer helped me grasp it

Answer (score 0):

When no `constructor` is declared, the `new` operator only creates an empty object with `Circle.prototype` as prototype. If you want to initialize some properties of the class instance, then you need a `constructor`.

You have another alternative, if the property you want to create doesn't depend on the constructor parameters, then you can use [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) as an equivalent:

```
class Foo {
  // this is equivalent to a constructor initialization but it only takes a static assignment
  bar = 'bar';
}
```

[Class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) adds properties on the class instance just like a `constructor` does.

Comment: Thank you Guerric, I appreciate the depth of this answer.   

From this I understand that a ```constructor``` is needed so that each instance has unique members. If I have no need for unique parameters, I can leave the ```constructor``` out. (in which case, a function or const may suffice!)   

Sound out if this is barking up the wrong concept?

Comment: Yes in short: if you need class members that depend on the constructor parameters, then you obviously need a constructor. If you need statically assigned class members, you can use class fields (they are still scoped to the class **instance** and can be reassigned later just like any other class member). And then class methods are being assigned to the prototype and are shared between all the instances.